# Running count starting from first date in selected date range (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am aiming to show a running count over each day from the start of a selected month to the end of it. So starting at 1 and ending at however many records have been added over that period.

The date range is selected using a slicer in the Power BI report.

I'm using this DAX code in a measure, but instead of starting the count within the selected range, it begins with the total up until that point (outside of the selected date range) and adds to it.

```
4.0 RUNNING COUNT = CALCULATE(COUNT('GDO DRDD_Tracking_Report_View'[ACTIVITY]),
FILTER(ALLSELECTED('GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate]),
'GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate] < MAX('GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate])
))
```

[image]

Can anyone advise as to how I can get the running total to begin from the start of a selected month?

Answer (score 0):

Are you only showing a single month at a time? Or are you showing a range of months, so the value resets on the first of each month?

Basically, just use FILTER() to adjust your evaluation context, something like this (note: I have a Calendar dimension, which makes this easy). This is my measure, but I'm filtering those results with a dropdown slicer so I can only select a single [MonthYear] at a time.

```
Running Order Count over Month = 
CALCULATE([Order Count],
    FILTER(
        ALL('DimDate'[DayNumberOfMonth]),
        'DimDate'[DayNumberOfMonth]<=MAX('DimDate'[DayNumberOfMonth])
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Pieter. This his didn't achieve the requirement to count from the start of the range.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to meet the requirement using the code below.

They key was adding the code relating to the min date and ensuring that the variable holding this was evaluated in the context of the filter selection rather than the entire dataset.

```
7.0 Running Count = 
//VAR SelectedStartDate = MIN('GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate])
VAR SelectedStartDate = MINX(ALLSELECTED('GDO Dim_Dates'),'GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate])
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate])

RETURN CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('GDO DRDD_Tracking_Report_View'),
        FILTER(
            ALL('GDO Dim_Dates'),
            'GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate] >= SelectedStartDate &&
            'GDO Dim_Dates'[TheDate] <= CurrentDate
        )
    )
```